# Why am I getting an error with this using statement without brackets? .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
var webRequest2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/my/url");
var response2 = client2.Send(webRequest2);
var reader2 = new StreamReader(response2.Content.ReadAsStream());
var responseBody2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();

using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseBody2);
```

Getting

```
error CS1002: ; expected
error CS0103: The name 'jsonDoc' does not exist in the current context
```

on that last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script/issues/611) explains what's going on:

> Unfortunately this is a limitation of Roslyn. You cannot use using statements as global script variables.

You can only use `using` statements inside a scope. Even if you put curly braces around just that line:

```
{
    using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseBody2);
}
```

*Old answer:*

The [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) was introduced in C# 8.0. Your project is probably using a lower version, so it only understands `using` as a [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

Comment: I am using .Net 6 and the default language is C#10. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Are you sure that error is from that line then?

Comment: I'll also add that I am using dotnet-script v1.3.1 - for rapid unit testing

Comment: It's literally the last statement in my script, and those two errors are the only output, and reference that last line

Comment: @ChrisHarrington The fact you're using dotnet-script is important information. See my update.

Comment: Putting {} around all my code did indeed make the compiler happy. Thanks for pointing that issue out.